# What do the Vedas & other scriptures say about sex during pregnancy?

Tags: vedas, sex

I read in some answers that sex is an act reserved for reproduction. I have also read in line with the same that sex is only touching the physical dimensions of our existence. For spiritual growth abstinence is; one of many prescriptions.

However, I am curious what the scriptures have to say about sex during pregnancy specifically. What are the effects? Thank you.